# How to simulate different locale for testing regional currency display of Android billing sku?

Tags: android, localization, in-app-purchase

I have an existing app that is on Google Play that uses in app billing. I am already successfully connecting to `IInAppBillingService` and getting the SKU details:

```
    Bundle details = mBillingService.getSkuDetails(BILLING_VERSION, getPackageName(), "subs", skuBundle);
    ArrayList<String> skuDetails = details.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(skuDetails.get(0));
    String localizedCost = jobj.getString("price");
```

I am trying to simulate different regions in order to make sure I'm complying with Google's June 16 2020 requirement that values be displayed in local currency.

I've set my phone's preferred language to Spanish and Japanese but the SKU keeps returning values in USD.

I've googled and everything I find seems to point to the fact that Google Play is determining my locale based on my true region as recognized on Google Play and possibly the region or billing address of my credit card.

So how then can we simulate other regions to test this requirement?